# Installing 32-bit Access 2007 on a Terminal Server that already has 64-bit Office 2010 installed on it?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server, 32bit-64bit, microsoft-office, app-v

The users at my organization connect to a Terminal Server running **Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard**.

They use **Outlook 2010** on their profiles when they log in, and for this reason **64-bit Office 2010** has been installed, probably using that `Control Panel -> Programs -> Install Application on Remote Desktop` method of installing software.  It appears that **64-bit Office 2010** was installed in full including **MS-Access 2010**.

Our users also need to be able to access just **32-bit MS-Access 2007** to work with some old, old databases via **32-bit ODBC** that connect to an old, old system we are slated to get rid of *"when the new system is ready"*.

Now I know that it is possible to uninstall just **64-bit MS-Access 2010** without removing all the rest of **64-bit MS-Office 2010**, but I'm not certain it's possible to reinstall just **32-bit MS-Access 2007** without some sort of a registry hack.

I have **32-bit MS-Access 2007** and **32-bit MS-Access 2003** installed on my own **64-bit Windows 7** box for purposes of maintaining these databases and a registry hack is being used to switch between them, but I can't imagine this being possible in a multi-user environment like Terminal Server.

Is there some way of making this work?

Comment: 1. Microsoft recommends installing 32bit Office on 64bit Windows. 2. Why not just create 32bit DSN's for the connections to the external data? I don't see why 32bit Access is required if you only need a 32bit ODBC connection.

Comment: @joeqwerty I'm using a no longer supported Visual Fox Pro driver that I have to shoehorn into Windows 7 with a registry hack to normally get it to work, if that makes any difference...

Comment: I'm confused now, what does Windows 7 have to do with it? Does the Access connection originate from the RDS server and go to a Fox Pro database on a Windows 7 computer?

Comment: Everything I have read from Microsoft suggestions that the 32bit version of Offices is incompatible with the 64bit version.  You can only have components from one arch installed on a single system.  Though, I have read you can use App-V to get around this.

Comment: @joeqwerty, perhaps you are aware of something I am not, but I thought I read somewhere that 64 bit version of access could not use 32bit ODBC drivers.

Comment: @Zoredache It's true!  The 64-bit version of MS Office cannot access 32-bit ODBC drivers.

Comment: Is the "App-V Management Server" a way to use App-V to install both versions of Office on a Terminal Server?  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2714.how-to-install-and-configure-the-app-v-management-server-en-us.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you must co-mingle multiple versions of Office, you should installed the oldest versions first, in order.  No configurations are supported by Microsoft.

**How to use Office 2010 suites and programs on a computer that is running another version of Office**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2121447